# How is the accuracy of Cristian's clock synchronization algorithm (t + RTT - min)?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

I was reading lecture notes on Cristian's clock synchronization algorithm.

The algorithm states the following assumptions :

- The minimum value of the client-server one way transmission time is : **min**
- The server timestamps the message at the last possible
  instant before sending it back.

Suppose a client sends a request message for time synchronization from the server.

The server timestamps its current time **T** and responds back.

Assuming both sending time == receiving time, the client sets its clock to T + (RTT/2) where RTT is the round trip time.  It says the accuracy of this is in the bound ( T + min, T + RTT - min).

My proof that this is wrong :

Let the sending transmission time Tc = min + x where x >= 0.

This is because the term x introduces an unbounded sending delay which is not known to us.

Let the receiving transmission time Ts = min + y where y >=0 (y is a similar term as x for the reverse direction).

Time to set the client's clock is therefore T + Ts.

Also RTT = Tc + Ts = 2min + x + y

Minimum possible bound for the time that can be set = T + min when y = 0.

Maximum possible bound for the time that can be set = T + RTT - (min + x).

Since T + RTT - (min + x) <= T + RTT - min, we must be setting our clock to more than the server's time if the bound stated in the book/lecture is correct. Where am I going wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: What actually is wrong? In your description there are many things that may be wrong. Point to the one you have in mind.

Comment: The accuracy of Cristian's clock synchronization mentioned in the book was (T + min, T + RTT - min) which is the range giving the minimum possible time to set and maximum possible time to set. In other words, a guarantee that the server is not ahead than T + RTT - min. I think this is wrong as I show here that T + RTT - (min + x) <= T + RTT - min.